# Recorrer los elementos de un Dropdown (Select Option) con $interval AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

necesito recorrer los elementos de un dropdownlist que he llenado previamente con un servicio, Que se mantenga en un elemento 30 segundos y luego pase al siguiente.

**Mi HTML:**

```
 <select ng-model="depSel" ng-change="changedValue(depSel)" class="form-control pull-right animated fadeInRight" style="width: 260px;font-size:17px;">
        <option value="">--- Seleccione Dependencia ---</option>
        <option ng-repeat="dependencia in dependencias" value="{{dependencia}}">{{dependencia}}</option>
  </select>
```

**Mi app.js:**

```
$scope.dependencias = {};
    DepSrv.cargar().then( function(){
    $scope.dependencias = DepSrv.config.data.DEPENDENCIAS;
});
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Una opción podría ser ciclar sobre el array de dependencias y actualizar el ng-model:

```
  $scope.index = 0;

  $interval(function() {
    $scope.index = ($scope.index == $scope.dependencias.length)? 0: $scope.index +1;
    $scope.depSel = ($scope.index == $scope.dependencias.length) ? $scope.dependencias[0] : $scope.dependencias[$scope.index + 1];
  }, 30000);
```

Dejo un ejemplo en plunker para ver si realmente es lo que necesitas:
http://plnkr.co/edit/c8GG9L5njWcAUILGTGUP?p=preview

Espero que sea lo que estás buscando, si no lo es, no dudes en volver a preguntar. Saludos.

Comment: Excelente.! Eres un genio, gracias.! +1
Me podrias explicar o indicar donde puedo leer sobre lo que hiciste.?

Comment: De nada, saludos!

Comment: Me podrias explicar o indicar donde puedo leer sobre lo que hiciste.? Eso del "?" y el "0:" disculparas la molestia.

($scope.index == $scope.dependencias.length)? 0: $scope.index +1;

Comment: Podés leer sobre operador ternario acá: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Conditional_Operator